# Backup App Maker Data Nightly

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to do a nightly backup of an App Maker database? Just in case a user accidentally deletes any data?

Even just having an outputted spreadsheet would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an clock based [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that will execute once a day in the morning before office hours.

This piece of code will be on a Server side script and will look something like this:

```js
function createInstallableTrigger() {
  // Runs at 5am in the timezone of the script
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("backUp")
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(5)
  .everyDays(1) // Frequency is required if you are using atHour() or nearMinute()
  .create();
}

function backUp() {
  try {
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getActiveSheet(),
        dataToBackUp = [],
        globalKeys = {
          model: ["first_name", "last_name", "email"],
          label: ["First Name", "Last Name", "Email"]
        },
    var records = app.models.requests.newQuery().run();
    if(records.length >= 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        var newLine = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < globalKeys.model.length; x++) {
          newLine.push(records[i][globalKeys.model[x]]);
        }
        dataToBackUp.push(newLine);
        // at the end, push it all on the spreadsheet
        if(i === records.length - 1) {
          // check if there is any entry at all
          if(dataToBackUp.length >= 1) {
            // append column titles first
            spreadSheet.appendRow(globalKeys.label);
            // 
            spreadSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataToBackUp.length, globalKeys.model.length).setValues(dataToBackUp);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Let us know if it worked, if it did, please choose this as the answer :)

Comment: So I apologize as a lot of this code is over my head. So I would create a Server Side Script and copy that code in there, right? Where would it create/store the spreadsheet? Also, for the model/label section would I need to enter each label for every model in the whole app? If so that might be more trouble than it is worth due to the number of labels and the fact they are still changing. I know I can do a manual Export Data from the Deployments section. My hope was that there might be a way to just initiate that without having to do it manually. But I'm guess that might be the simpler option.